# Pass selected value from dropdownlistfor back to controller via Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have this code in my view:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("TradeUKKPIShowData", "Report")) //action/controller
 { %>
  <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: #eeeeee; width: 300px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
      <div style="float: left; width: 150px; padding-top: 3px;">
        <%: Html.Label("Select a Sunday:") %>
      </div>
      <div style="float: left; width: 150px;">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSunday, Model.AllSundays) %>
      </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align:right; width: 272px; padding-top: 30px;">
    <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
<% } %>
```

The action in the controller:

```
  public ActionResult TradeUKKPIShowData(DateTime date) //this date value is null thus error
  {
  var reportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPISearches(date);
  ViewBag.reportdate = date;
  return View(reportData);
  }
```

I get an error stating that the parameter passed, date, is null
where have i gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

ModelBinding won't work for a parameter named `date` because its different from the name of your select field. Use the proper name in your action parameter.

```
public ActionResult TradeUKKPIShowData(DateTime SelectedSunday) {}
```

You could also bind your ViewModel (don't know the type so i use `TypeOfYourViewModel`)

```
public ActionResult TradeUKKPIShowData(TypeOfYourViewModel model) 
{
     var reportData = _reportingService.GetTradeUKKPISearches(model.SelectedSunday);
     ViewBag.reportdate = date;
     return View(reportData);
}
```